# Angularjs not letting me specify filter on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat list of items I'd like to filter based on a set of check boxes on a page. I have a search box that I have linked up to work with filtering successfully - however when I want to specify search queries in ng-clicks I am misunderstanding the scope of the variables, or how they are linked I think.

Below is my code I am trying to use to modify the search criteria.

```
<button ng-click="searchText = a">Click me</button>
<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
```

A bit further down is my ng-repeat with a filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in present | filter:searchText">
```

However I am not able to set the searchtext to 'a' once a user clicks the button.

Putting it in the scope seems to change the variable itself but not update the filter, and I'm not sure I understand why this is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to it to be `String` `a`

then

```
<button ng-click="searchText = 'a'">Click me</button>
```

defined `a` as a string `'a'`,

If we define it as `<button ng-click="searchText = a">Click me</button>` then `a` must be a variable bound to scope.

Comment: I can not believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: :)  glad to help u, cheerz

Answer (score 2):

The expression within `ng-click="searchText = a"` is assigning the value of `searchText` to a scope variable `a` which would be undefined.

Quote the string value:

```
ng-click="searchText = 'a'"
```